# I can not see running docker compose containers on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: django, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

I have web app in 3 containers running on linux server (ubuntu 20.04), Django webapp, nginx webserver and postgres db. When i run 'docker-compose ps' it does not show any container, or error, only headings, like there is no container, not even crashed one.

I am sure that it is the right folder as there is no other docker-compose.yml on this server.

It seems almost like app is not running there except that it is accessible via browser and working well.

I tried all kinds of commands for showing containers or images using docker and docker-compose with no result

I tried `docker service restart` - app went offline for a moment and then back online (I have 'restart: allways' set in compose file) also I restarted the whole server with the same result.

Even script which is making db dumb does not see containers and started do fail

When I try to bring up the project running `docker-compose up` webapp and db containers starts but webserver not because port is already taken

Have anyone experienced this? I work with docker-compose for a while but it never happened to me before, I don't know what to do, I need to update the code of this application and I don't want to lose data in DB (I am also not able to make dump or ssh to the container).

This app was working for years with the same configuration before, on the other server with Ubuntu 18.04. Maybe it is server related problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is some fundamental problem going on. Have you tried using simply `docker ps` to see if your containers are running, or to see if anything is running?

If the containers are listed in the `docker ps` output, make sure you have the names correct in your `docker-compose.yml`

If you don't see your containers running with `docker ps` then maybe they crashed immediately after start (and are therefore no longer running).

I would have expected `docker-compose ps` to have shown something - even if your containers are crashing.

Please provide more details of your output from `docker ps` and/or `docker-compose ps` and maybe the contents of your `docker-compose.yml` if these things don't help. You said "it doesn't show any container" when you run `docker-compose ps` - does it show anything at all (errors, blank lines, etc.)

Comment: `docker ps`  `docker-compose ps` also with `-a` option all shows the same, no containers, no errors, only headings `Name   Command   State   Ports` and line under that, like there is no conteiner, even not running one... containers are not crashing because app is working and accessible via browser, also `docker-compose ps` would show crashed containers... This app was working for years with the same configuration before, on the other server with Ubuntu 18.04. Maybe it is server related problem.